# Is there a faster code for adding a new row to a table - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I add a new row to a table, everytime my code finds a new value to add to it.
The code I use for this `Set newRow = ProjectTable.ListRows.Add` works fine.
but this makes it run very slow.

Is there a code that accomplishes the same but runs quicker?

```
Dim ProjectName As String
Dim ResourceType As String
Dim newRow As ListRow
Dim RPLastRow As Long
RPLastRow = RPSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For Each cell In RPSheet.Range("A5:A" & RPLastRow)
    If cell = project Then
        Dim cRow As Long
        cRow = cell.Row

        'enter resource type to table
        ResourceType = RPSheet.Range("B" & cRow).Value
        Set newRow = ProjectTable.ListRows.Add
        newRow.Range(1, 1).Value = ResourceType

        'find amount of resources linked to project and add number to table
        ProjectName = project
        newRow.Range(1, 2).Value = Sheet2.NumberOfResources(ProjectName, ResourceType)
    End If
Next cell
```

EDIT: Added some extra code so its more clear

Comment: Have you tried adding the data first to the end of the table and then adding that range to the table range?

Comment: In case your table has calculated cells, the slow down is caused all the calculated cells being calculated again every time you add a new item. I would suggest you turn of the calculation & screen updating for the time the code is being executed `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` and `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` (and at the end of code set to `xlCalculationAutomatic` and `True`)

Comment: I don't use automatic calculations in the sheet. Thanks for the comment though ;)

Comment: Oddly I've also seemed to notice it gets worse the longer the workbook (or perhaps Excel [2007] has been open).  When I run it from scratch, it seems to be faster.  Memory issues????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The faster way is to add data to the end of the table and then simply resize it.

Here is an example

```
ProjectTable.Resize Range("$A$1:$E$" & lRow)
```

Where `lRow` is the new last row